# How to fix price sensitive transaction fee?

Tags: ether

I am developing a Ethereum dAapp where deploying small certificates on the blockchain is required, multiple times. But Ethereum price fluctuations that can make you happy as an investor, can make you sad as a dApp user, because a transaction might be simply too expensive in terms of fiat. So I would like to know:

1. why Ethereum does not have a dynamic gas limit bottom or something like that, to solve this problem?
2. do any projects on top of ethereum solve, at least partially, this problem?
3. alternately, do any other platforms allow you to keep a stable fee in terms of fiat?

Answer (score 1):

The gas price *is* dynamic: The amount you have to send is just a matter of how much miners will require to include their transaction in their block. Whether or not that price scales with the rise and fall of ETH depends on the market, but there are some elements like orphan risk that would make it rational for miners to let the fiat price rise as ETH rises.

Making the gas price stable is difficult because it reacts to congestion; One solution would be to remove the congestion, which is the goal of scaling-related work like sharding. If the congestion goes away, gas pricing can either be stable or be low enough that the variation doesn't matter.

In theory it may be possible to make a contract that would insure you against gas price increases, but this may be difficult in practice since the upper costs are effectively unlimited, and I don't know of any projects that are doing this.

Comment: When i started in october the average transaction fee was back then 15cents, now it can reach 2, 3 or even 4usd. What if Ethereum price will be 10k usd or even more in the future? dapps will be too expensive, maybe I ignore something but it seems to me that nobody cares

Comment: This is mainly caused by network congestion, not the price of ETH. It's a serious problem, and the solution is better scaling to reduce congestion.

Comment: So basically with a ETH price increase users should be able to lower their gas price when making transactions. to keep reasonable fiat fee values, but it doesn't happen because of scalability reasons... therefore fees (in terms of wei) remain practically the same or even higher, am I right?